# Subscript operator overload and reference to pointer error

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, subscript

I'm struggling with a strange error for a while now and I need your help :D

I have an 'Image' class declared like

```
template <typename P>
class Image {
// ...
public: // Operators 
    Color<P>*& operator [] ( unsigned int const& i );
// ...
}
```

Since it's the first time I overload this operator, I'm not really sure of it (especially the *& part...)

The troube appears when I tried something like :

```
/// Sample Code
Image<P> img; img[0][0] = Color<double>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

I get

```
./src/Graphics/PNGWriter.cc:12:3: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘img[0]’
./src/Graphics/Image.cc:24:12: note: candidate is: Color<P>*& Image<P>::operator[](const unsigned int&) [with P = double] <near match>
```

Obviously the  obscucate a bit more the solution to me...

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does Color<P> have an overloaded operator[]?

Comment: Nop, why would it have one (I mean, it could to index RGB component but for this problem in particular ) ?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Please post a complete, concise [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

All "no match for '...'" errors mean the arguments in the call aren't compatible to the declared arguments for any functions or operators, so you should look to the argument declarations. Make argument to `operator[]` an unsigned int. Similarly, passing the returned pointer by reference is quite odd; not necessarily bad, but highly suspect. In general, non-compound types should be passed by value.

Comment: Actually I tried that but since It didn't match the exact signature, I tried this one...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to pass so many things by reference.  Taking the unsigned int by value would almost certainly not slow things down; same about the reference to pointer.

This could be the problem, but I doubt it;  I don't see why 0 wouldn't convert to a `unsigned int const&`.  Another possibility is that the image is actually `const`, but you failed to mention that in your paste.  Subscript operators generally come in pairs; you need to declare another one as `Color<P> const* operator [] ( unsigned int i ) const;`.

Note that `img[0]` is what is being complained about, so the `= Color<double>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` is probably not an issue (unless there's some SFINAE error I'm missing).  Finally, make sure you haven't specialised `Image` for `double`.

EDIT:  By the way, returning `Color<P>*&` has a severe disadvantage;  someone could do `img[0] = 0`, which was probably not the way the class was meant to be used.